# JQuery Mobile slider not working fastly in windows Phone 8

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

Hi i am working on Phonegap, and I am using the jQuery Mobile for **Windows Phone8**  app. The range slider isn't being dragged simultaneously with the finger movement. It is working for the finger tapping.

Could you please give me any suggestions, thank You.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6561

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into using Kendo Mobile, as I have found the jquery mobile is not always reliable, or speedy.  Kendo Mobile works with phonegap to. Also keep in mind that not every feature works in the windows phones, as they do for Iphone or Android.